# Laravel 4 - blade Images don't display properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, templating

I experienced an issue displaying my images via Laravel blade templating.

In my "change-profile.blade.php" file I have a form that allows authenticated users to change some profile info. In this specific case I want to display avatars based on gender input provided.

So far so good, my js works perfectly and my images url seems to be ok in terms of path.
The problem is images result broken and I seriously don't know why. 
This is my code:

```
@extends('layout.main')
@section('content')
    <form action="{{ URL::route('profile-change-profile') }}" method="post">
        <fieldset class="change-profile">
            <legend>Change Profile</legend>
            <p>
                <input type="radio" class="gender" name="gender" value="male" /><span>male</span>
                <input type="radio" class="gender" name="gender" value="female" /><span>female</span> 
            </p>
            <p>
                <ul class="males gender">
                    @for ($i = 0; $i < 75; $i++)
                        <li><img src="{{ asset('assets/img/avatar/males/m-' . ($i+1) . '.png') }}" alt="avatar_male_{{ $i+1 }}"></li>
                    @endfor
                </ul>
                <ul class="females gender">
                    @for ($i = 0; $i < 40; $i++)
                        <li><img src="{{ asset('assets/img/avatar/females/f-' . ($i+1) . '.png') }}" alt="avatar_female_{{ $i+1 }}"></li>
                    @endfor
                </ul>
                <input type="hidden" class="avatar-src" name="avatar-src" value="" />
            </p>
            <p class="form-action">
                <button type="submit">submit</button>
                {{ Form::token() }}
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
@stop
```

My images are stored as png files in public/assets/img/avatar/(females|males)/(m|f)-n.png

Any help?

Comment: What does the resulting HTML look like?

Comment: everything works fine, I mean I don't have any error in my view and links seem to be correct except for images that are broken, so probably there's something I wrote incrrectly.

Comment: @ceejayoz RESULT (I copy just first result for example):
'<li><img src="http://localhost:8888/wankster/v2/public/assets/img/avatar/males/m-1.png" alt="avatar_male_1"></li>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found!
It wasn't something wrong in my code but just folder encryption.
With folder encryption (due to zip folder or zip file saved on OSX) those files exist upon unzip process but they're not accessible (from a browser) until you disable the encryption itself manually.
You can avoid this annoying problem experienced on Windows just right-clicking on "green" filename/folder, select advanced and get rid of the tick related to encryption (last one tick, left-bottom).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
<li><img src="/assets/img/avatar/male/m-{{$i+1}}.png" alt="avatar_male_{{ $i+1 }}"></li>

<li><img src="/assets/img/avatar/females/f-{{$i+1}}.png" alt="avatar_female_{{ $i+1 }}"></li>
```

Comment: It doesn't change, I still can't access to these resources

Comment: What do you see when you view the source of the link?

Comment: Eg does http://localhost:8888/assets/img/avatar/male/m-1.png in your url produce any results? Have you tried http://localhost:8888/public/assets/img/avatar/male/m-1.png

Comment: Thank you Nick, I found the solution and it wasn't a problem due to my code but it was just about encryption of the folder